# Do promises in a React lifecycle methods pause subsequent lifecycle methods?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux, lifecycle

My understanding is that lifecycle methods are asynchronous. I want my action dispatch in `componentWillMount` to resolve before `render` is run.

One way of controlling async behavior is using promises for your redux actions, where you use `setState` to wait to control things in `render`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.myDispatchedAction().then(() => {
    this.setState({loaded: true})
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.loaded ? <div>waited for promise</div> : null }
    </div>
  )
}
```

But if it's the mere fact that a promise is being used (if it halts `render`?), would you be able to sync it the same way with async/await by just doing this?

```
async componentWillMount() {
  await this.props.myDispatchedAction()
}
```

Comment: where did you get the understanding that those methods where asynchronous? i couldn't find the documentation for it

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I could very easily be wrong. If lifecycle events are synchronous, does that mean my async/await example would work?

Comment: lol, i was genuinely asking because you got me curious.

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks synchronous, `async/await` is basically syntactic sugar for Promise. As such, it is still asynchronous so the functionality should not change.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context as to what you mean by "functionality should not change"? Are you referring to the functionality compared to .then + this.setState or do you mean using async/await with my sample code doesn't affect how the component is rendered at all?

Comment: I may be wrong, but what I mean is that by using _async/await_ you would not "halt" the execution of `componentWillMount()`. In your case, there would be a difference between the two versions because of what I said (`render()` would be called while the Promise is still pending).